# jenkins master connection fails with java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

Tags: java, git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Job which runs every hours, from a Master(Jenkins on Ubuntu) to Windows 10 machine as slave, 30-40 % of the time job just fails with following error. I need some help where to start looking or what is a possible solution for this.

Both Master and Slave have same Java version "1.8.0_151"

```
   FATAL: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
   java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
   Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from p578c1cb8.dip0.t-ipconnect.de/67.110.18.114:55940
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1693)
        at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:192)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:907)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:986)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:975)
        at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1158)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1200)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1724)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Caused: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:329)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:992)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer.onReadClosed(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:208)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.onRecvClosed(ApplicationLayer.java:222)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(ProtocolStack.java:832)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.FilterLayer.onRecvClosed(FilterLayer.java:287)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:181)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.switchToNoSecure(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:283)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processWrite(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:503)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processQueuedWrites(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:248)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:200)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doCloseSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:213)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.doCloseSend(ProtocolStack.java:800)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.doCloseWrite(ApplicationLayer.java:173)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer$ByteBufferCommandTransport.closeWrite(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:311)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1405)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1358)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.closeChannel(SlaveComputer.java:737)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.access$800(SlaveComputer.java:96)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$3.run(SlaveComputer.java:655)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Step ‘Publish Robot Framework test results’ failed: no workspace for T_REG #117
ERROR: Step ‘E-mail Notification’ failed: no workspace for T_REG #117
Email was triggered for: Failure - Any
Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any
ERROR: Error: No workspace found!
Sending email to: tw.aa@gmail.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to a memory error, as stated in [this bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50132)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you may have an issue with using secret credentials on a virtual slave.

From [Here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48200):

> ... best path forward is to create a git client authentication token class which uses AuthenticationTokens.convert() to map specific credentials (username/password or ssh private key) to the git client, then that git client authentication token would be sent over the wire from the master to the agent, rather than sending the Secret over the wire.

Maybe try using a [credential plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-binding-plugin)?

*<sub><sub>Also might I suggest removing your email from the snippet</sub></sub>*

Comment: What is hinting you at this?

Comment: Trial and error experience with something similar. Anecdotal at best